# Get values from vars inside class across other functions

Tags: php, function, class

```
class dir_exam 
{
    public $db_ruta;

    function __construct($db_ruta) 
    { 
      $this->db_ruta=$db_ruta; 
    }

    function veritas() 
    { 
        $aa="ok"; 
        $xx="ok2";

        return $aa; 
        return $xx; 
    }

    function create_d() 
    {
        $r=$this->veritas(); 
        echo $r->$aa; 
        echo $r->$xx; 
    }
}
```

I have this class and i try execute funtion veritas inside function create_d, but i want show the value from function veritas as individual values, showing value in create_d for $aa and $xx, when execute finally the class

```
<?php
    $a=new dir_exam("db_p");
    echo $a->create_d();
?>
```

But i can´t get this finally, i don´t know if it´s not possible or what, this it´s my question, thank´s in advanced

Comment: You can't have multiple `return` statements in a row (well you "can", but only the first one will execute). There are many other little things that don't make much sense in this code, I'd recommend taking a loop at [OOP basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) on the manual.

Comment: There is a way to have multiple return values (it's called php generators) but I don't think that you are trying to achieve that. Currently, it will only return $aa. Your veritas function should return a simple array. I guess that's fully enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have 2 or more returns in a function.

For you use the vars $aa and $xx like OOP, you must create the 2 var in the class

```
class dir_exam 
{    
    public $db_ruta;
    public $aa; // <--
    public $xx; // <--
}
```

After, you need change the function *veritas* to pass the value for your attributes

```
   function veritas() 
   { 
        $this->aa="ok"; 
        $this->xx="ok2";
    }
```

Now in your function you can call like that:

```
function create_d() 
{
    $this->veritas(); 
    echo $this->aa; 
    echo $this->xx; 
}
```

Comment: I agree with setting `$aa` and `$xx` as properties, but `veritas()` doesn't return anything, so `$r` will be undefined. I think `create_d()` should probably just reference `$this->aa`, etc. as well.

Comment: I refactored the function create_d(), try it again